# Importing Data as an arbitrary matrix

Tags: matrix, import

I have a `.txt` file which have following form

`Name1 number1 number2 number3
Name2 number4 number5 number6 
Name3 number6 number8 number9`

I want to import these data as following matrix

`new={{number1,number2,number3,number4,number5,number6,number7,number8,number9}}`

namely a 1x9 matrix. When I try this code

`new = Part[Import["path\filename.txt", "Table"], Range[1, 3],2 ;; 4]`

I get a 3x3 matrix as

`new={{number1,number2,number3},{number4,number5,number6},{number7,number8,number9}}`

due to using the `Part` command. How can I build a 1x9 matrix where all numbers are placed in one row by importing data from the file or convert the 3x3 matrix obtained from above code to a 1x9 matrix?

Comment: Apply `Flatten` to `new`.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher Thanks, but this command give me a 9x1 matrix rather than 1x9 one. Do you know a way which produces a 1x9 matrix by importing data from the file directly?

Comment: Well, the matrix is _stored_ as $3 \times 3$ matrix, so we _have_ to convert it. Fasted way to obtain a $1 \times 9$ matrix might be `ArrayReshape[new, {1, Times @@ Dimensions[new]}]`.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher That's right! it works perfectly. Thanks. Can you explain about your code a bit?

Comment: Well, have a look into the documentation of `ArrayReshape`. `Times @@ Dimensions[new]` just computes $3 \cdot 3 = 9$ in a way that also works for other matrix sized of `new`.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher Right, I applied it to my original matrix which was a 14x7 matrix. I will study the documentation.

Comment: Ah, and btw.: You're welcome.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher Thanks,It seems you're expert in Mathematica, Is there a way that I ask you my questions about Mathematica privatley?

Comment: Well, if it's not too many questions, you can contact me under this email address: `Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPClZiYGAoTs4ozU1MzkgtcsjMKy7JTSzJ0CsqL8nQTQQJ5umlpAIANGgO/A=="]`. (Execute the command in Mathematica.) But also [this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) provides much helpful info for new users.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher  Thanks a lot, what a cute way!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher an answer should be posted so this doesn't show up as "Unanswered"

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness:

```
With[{new = Import["path\filename.txt", "Table"]},
  ArrayReshape[new, {1, Times @@ Dimensions[new]}
]
```